# connection pool is returning null

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am new to Java, and trying to see why does the

```
 private static PoolConnectionManager pcm = null;
 con = pcm.getConnection();
 ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM employee");
```

returns null,
whereas when I set

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");      
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

connection seem to work fine.

what am I doing wrong with the connection pool thats messing the connection?

Comment: How is `pcm` defined?

Comment: i have it as private static PoolConnectionManager pcm = null; where the poolconnectionmanager class has all the url, username, password, and other properties.

Comment: pcm must be initialized, if you leave it as null and don't construct it with `new` or get it from some factory method, it will be a null reference

Comment: How do I construct it with new or get it from some factory method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `pcm` is initialized as `null` in your code. `null` is a non-existent value, meaning your PoolConnectionManager is non-existent. You need to initialize your PoolConnectionManager with an actual PoolConnectionManager instance in order to use any of its methods. You would usually do this using the `new` keyword, for example `private static PoolConnectionManager pcm = new PoolConnectionManager();`, filling in the constructor parameters as necessary.

The reason the second code block works is because DriverManager has a static method called `getConnection`. A static method can be accessed from the Class object itself, without having to create an instance of that class, which is what you're doing here. The first code line doesn't actually do anything.